# Openshift cors request returns 405 method not allowed

Tags: flask, cors, openshift, wildfly

I have the following setup on openshift:

- one application running wildfly 8 and mysql (A) - sort of a REST api.
- one application running a flask app through wsgi (B) - client app.

I want to do a POST request from B to A in order to authenticate. Locally I'm sort of running the same setup, port 8080 for A, 5000 for B and everything works smoothly (of course it does :P), but doing this on openshift I get a 405 response.

Another thing that I've noticed is that if I do the same request from a chrome rest client(Postman) to A the call completes ok, so I'm starting to think that maybe there's something wrong with B, but I can't find anything on the openshift app and again ... locally it behaves as expected.

The flask app uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. Snippet from login method bellow:

```
url = API_ROOT + '/login'
payload = {'userId': username, 'password': password}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
return requests.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can u share the request URL that you trying from B, and method/view/route definitionform A

Comment: @kartheek - I've updated the question with a code snippet for the login method, but as far as url, I'm not at liberty to share.

Comment: Are you making the request to your http://app-domain.rhcloud.com url? And are you making the request to port 80?

Comment: Hey, the request is made to the app id, but i don't specify the port information. As a side note, after restarting the python app the request performed ok. Haven't got a chance to see exactly why, because i'm in a place with super bad internet connectivity.